# python + subproces.check_call: how to call functions in python?

Tags: python

So the initial problem was that:

```
# works(1)
subprocess.check_call(["ls", "-l"])

#works(2), but "-l" argument not passed to called process
subprocess.check_call(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)

#works(3) again
subprocess.check_call("ls -l", shell=True) 

#Exception(4): "bufsize must be an integer"
subprocess.check_call("ls", "-l", shell=True)
```

if look at documention(https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html),
subprocess.check_call has such signature:
`subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`

I know function in python like this: `def f(*args, **kwargs)`, but
what mean `, *`? Is it the same as `*args`?

Any way, after that in documentation there is note that:

> The full function signature is the same as that of the Popen constructor

and Popen constructor signature is:

```
Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)
```

So it is clear why (4) failed, but why (2) works in wrong way?
And how to read this strange notation: `args, *, stdin=None`?

**Update**

I found why (2) is not working. Thanks for answer I understand
that from syntax point of view this is correct. So I run strace,
and see that python pass args to "/bin/sh" in wrong way.
Bug is known: http://bugs.python.org/issue6689 and rejected. This is sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is correct. The list `["ls", "-l"]` is passed as `args` to the method (`Popen.__init__`).

---

`*` denotes that argument after that are [*Keyword-only arguments*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). It is introduced in Python 3.x. But as you saw in the source code, the actual signature does not use keyword-only arguments. So you can pass positional arguments for arguments other than `args`.

Comment: But, in my post quotes from python 2.x documentation, if it is introduced in python 3, why it is used for python 2?

Comment: @user1034749, I'm not sure, but in my opinion, it seems like to encourage the reader of the documentation to use keyword arguments instead of positional argument for arguments after `args`.

Comment: Actually (2) is correct only from sytanx point view. But it is wrong on Linux from usage points view, because of http://bugs.python.org/issue6689. Thanks  for answering.